# How to redirect main site but now the whole domain in htacess

Tags: regex, expression

I have a domain, eg. `www.example.pl` and two sites. First site is under main domain - `www.example.pl`, but I have also second site at `www.example.pl/folder/`. Now I need redirect (301) only first site - `www.example.pl`, so site under .../folder/ I don't want redirect at all. I know that I need use RegEx expressions in `.htaccess` file on my server. Could someone show me how this expression should look properly? I was trying to that in past few hours but I've given up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 301 redirect just the root (www.example.pl) you can use `^/$`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://destination.com/
```

Comment: Wow! I did not expect is that simple! Thank U very much!